# Add class if (hidden) anchor is

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm writing a function to add a class to different menu items on several conditions.
The first condition is already working great but now I have something different.

I have a page with some tabs `#tab1`,`#tab2` and `#tab3`. However the anchor is invisible in the URL even if I switch between the tabs.

My current function:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    if(window.location.pathname.indexOf("/konto/adressen/") !==-1) {
        $(".jet-custom-nav__item-6068").addClass("current-menu-item");
    }
    else if(window.location.hash == "tab1") {
        $(".jet-custom-nav__item-9886").addClass("current-menu-item");
    }
});
```

The default tab page refresh is `#tab1`. After refresh the class is added to the right menu item but somehow my code makes the URL anchor visible and if I switch to another tab it stays still active. I would appreciate any help with this not too many experience by now!

Comment: What is `tab1`?

Comment: `substr()` doesn't test a condition, it returns a substring starting from a specified index. It's strange to use it in `if`

Comment: Can you try using `window.location.pathname` once. And also window.location.pathname.indexOf() will not work.

Comment: @Barmar tab1 is the URL anchor for this tab without the #. I edit it right now, I inserted the wrong code to the question.

Comment: @AdeshKumar window.location.pathname.indexOf() is already working but I try it with window.location.pathname for the anchor

Comment: You switch tabs.... does the url change? Do you remove and add another class?

Comment: `window.location.hash` includes the `#` character, so you need `== '#tab1'`